# Protege: reasoner HermiT won't complain about unmet assertion; why?

Tags: owl, protege, reasoning

I would be thankful for some explanation to the following.
I have created an ontology with Protege with a class that contains something like:

```
hasResult exactly 1 AccelerationDate
```

in its *SubClass Of* definitions.
Now when I create an individual of this class and I do **not** meet this condition, I would have expected for the integrated reasoner HermiT to complain about this but it doesn't. Can someone maybe explain why that is the case / where my understanding is lacking?

Comment: as always, *Open World Assumption* holds in OWL ontologies. And OWL is **not** a constraint language. Use SHACL or similar if you need constraints. OWL is made for inferences